# How to compute two animation durations being chained as .curveEaseIn and .constant in such a way we won't notice any glitch?

Tags: swift, animation, duration

I am rolling a large-width landscape image to give the impression to the user the whole stuff is a constant spinning cylinder.

To do that, the large image is actually made of two copies of the same image stitched together with constraints and embedded into a UIScrollView. As a consequence, when I animate the contentOfsset.x to make it horizontally scrolling, only the portion inside the UIScrollView is made visible.

When the scrollView appears, the visible portion shows the middle part of the image.

As I want to start with an ease-in curve, I animate it till the end of the image, when completed, I then set the contentOffset at the beginning of the image and run a new repeating animation as per the code follows:

```
    // set content offset at the center of the background
    let w = imageViews[0].frame.width
    let vw = view.frame.width
    backgroundScrollView.contentOffset.x = (w - vw)/2

    print ("\(#function): Background image view = \(imageViews[0].frame), start offset = \(backgroundScrollView.contentOffset.x), view  = \(view.frame)")

    let duration: TimeInterval = 10.0
    let speed = TimeInterval(w + vw) / duration
    let halfDuration = TimeInterval(w / 2 + vw) / speed

     UIView.animate(withDuration: halfDuration, delay: 0, options: [ .curveEaseIn ], animations: {
        self.backgroundScrollView.contentOffset.x =  w
     }){ completed in
        self.backgroundScrollView.contentOffset.x = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [ .repeat, .curveLinear ], animations: {
            self.backgroundScrollView.contentOffset.x = w
        }) { completed in
        }
    }
```

The point here, is that I compute the time for each animation depending on the distance it has to scroll (the first is almost the half of the second). Unfortunately, as the .curveEaseIn is not linear (and I still compute average speed) there is a small glitch in speed between the two animation.

Anyone knows what the curveEaseIn equation is? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: `UIView.animateKeyframes` might help.

Comment: +Ratnesh Jain: how would you repeat the last keyframe only?

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-create-keyframe-animations-using-animatekeyframes)

Comment: yep, but this does not provide any way to repeat the second keyframe forever. The only way to do it with key frame is to add zillion identical keys, which of course is not appropriate. Or I'm missing something.